# Can't render JSX inside a nested curly brace

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a react table like this

```
    function myComponent() {
       const rows = [some, data, from, http, request]
       const tableType = "rowForTable1"; // lets just say table1, but really this is dynamically retrived via http request.
    return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>
            <EnhancedTableToolbar numSelected={selected.length} />
            <TableContainer>
              <Table
             <TableBody>
                          {rows.map((row) => {             
                              {RowType(tableType.toLowerCase(), row).map((col) => { 
                                  console.log(col); // I can see the column values thru this
                                  <TableRow
                                    hover
                                    onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, row.name)}
                                    role="checkbox"
                                    aria-checked={isItemSelected}
                                    tabIndex={-1}
                                    key={row.name}
                                    selected={isItemSelected}
                                  >
                                    <TableCell key={col} align="right">{col}</TableCell> // BUT I CANNOT SEE THIS getting displayed in the page
                                  </TableRow>);
                              })}
                              
                          })}
                        </TableBody>
            </Table>
         </TableContainer>
       </Paper>
    </div>
);
}
        
        function RowType(tableType, row) {
          const funcMap = 
             rowForTable1: [row.tabl1Col1, row.tabl1Col2, row.tabl1Col3],
             rowForTable2: [row.tabl2Col1, row.tabl2Col2, row.tabl2Col3],
          }
        
          return funcMap[tableType];
        }
```

Rows are being passed to this table, and gets iterated by rows.map

so there are different table content display for different http request So I made the tablerow dynamic via the function RowType(TheTypeOfTable, andTheRow)

Now the problem is, I verified that the first and second(inner) **map** iteration is correct via console.log(the columns), it's just that the inner **map** which is responsible for rendering the `<TableRow>` does not display anything

Anyone has idea how to do this properly?

Comment: where have you wrapped the `<TableBody>` in?

Comment: @AniketAgarwal Updated my post to show the complete component function

Comment: I am confused how can you declare tableType inside the jsx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to `return` the TableRow from the map function.

```
        {rows.map((row) => ( // Here we use ROUND braces to auto return the next statement             
            RowType(tableType.toLowerCase(), row).map((col) => {
                console.log(col);
                return ( // return row
                    <TableRow
                        hover
                        onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, row.name)}
                        role="checkbox"
                        aria-checked={isItemSelected}
                        tabIndex={-1}
                        key={row.name}
                        selected={isItemSelected}>
                        <TableCell key={col} align="right">{col}</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                )
            })
        ))}
```

A map with curly braces and no return statement results in a void[] and nothing gets added in the parent.

A call like <TableRow> gets translated into a regular function call that returns an object. If you don't use the result then nothing is going to happen. There are no magic side effects.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know the round brace vs the curly one. this solved my problem.